# Changing styling of parent element without unique id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of divs identical to the one below

```
<div class="example">
```

Some of these divs have child nodes, which look something like this

```
<input type="submit" name="auto-gen" value="Extra" id="auto-gen" class="add-button" aria-label="" data-active="True" data-isfirstcontrol="False" type="button">
```

Due to working with legacy software, I can't change anything about the structure of these divs (can't change id's or change class name or anything). However, I want to be able to add some CSS (float: right;) to the example class, but only if they have a child with the "add-button" class.

I've been trying to do stuff like below:

```
$('.add-button').parent().style.styleFloat = 'right'
```

However, whatever I try I get the following error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'styleFloat').
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You're trying to mix jQuery code with plain DOM API code, and that doesn't work. What you want with jQuery is the `.css()` method: `$(".add-button").parent().css({float: "right"})`

Comment: You need to know if you have a jquery collection `$(".btn")` or a DOM node `.style...` - you *can* convert between the two but (as above) it's recommended that you stick with one or the other.  To convert your code, you *could* do `$(".btn").parent()[0].style.styleFloat...`

Comment: Also what is styleFloat? There is no css property called `style-float` which is what you are trying to set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no `.add-button` elements which `parent()` is not a `.example`, you can just target every `add-button` and style his `parent()`

---

Using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

```js
$(".add-button").parent().css({ float: "right" });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="example">
  
</div>

<div class="example">
    <input type="submit" name="auto-gen" value="Extra" id="auto-gen" class="add-button" aria-label="" data-active="True" data-isfirstcontrol="False" type="button">
</div>
```

---

Using plain [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)
<sup>[You might not need Jquery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)</sup>

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.add-button').forEach(e => e.parentNode.style.float = 'right')
```

```html
<div class="example">
  
</div>

<div class="example">
    <input type="submit" name="auto-gen" value="Extra" id="auto-gen" class="add-button" aria-label="" data-active="True" data-isfirstcontrol="False" type="button">
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Had no idea this was possible, thanks a bunch!